# how to have an optimized production build of vue app

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to `vue` and i am trying to build my simple (one component) test app. but i get 1.8 mb of js files after build.. i have added

```
module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  presets: [
  '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

to my `babel.config.js` but still getting the same result

im using `vue` version `2.6.10` and `webpack` version `4.28.4`

js file sizes after build:

`chunk-vendors.597c8310.js.map` 1,355 kb

`chunk-vendors.597c8310` 466 kb

`app.181cb770.js.map` 45 kb

`app.181cb770.js` 21 kb

Comment: 1.8mb seems pretty small. enable gzipping, caching, etc, you're fine

Comment: Are you using just webpack for your build or are you using something else as well e.g. grunt, gulp etc.?

Comment: If you use Vue CLI, `npm run build` creates a production build already. Also, I recommend using the `--report` flag (which uses `webpack-bundle-analyzer`) to see which dependencies are taking up space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) `*.map` aren't used by browser when DevTools is closed so the actual size of your JS is **`487kb`** !

2) It's hard to analyze what exactly causing such size. From the info you have provided `chunk-vendors.597c8310` looks really suspicious.

I guess you should start looking at your dependencies. I suppose you have something like `moment`, `lodash` or `vee-validate` in your bundle. If so, consider looking for altenatives (google).

3) To have the whole picture of dependencies you can use bundle analyzer built-in vue cli.

- open terminal in your project's dir
- type `vue ui` and open the url in browser (e.g. http://localhost:8000)
- make sure Vue UI is using you project
- build your app by clicking *Tasks* > *Build*
- switch to *Analyzer* tab
- check and remove "Big guys"

[image]

Comment: thanks that was really helpful, vue-material is a killer.. and i had it imported completely, now I'm only importing components that i need